# SQL Server - How to perform a calculation based on a dynamic formula

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have a case where I need to perform a dynamic calculation based on a particular entry in a column.

The table looks something like:

```
DECLARE Temp TABLE (
        Id INT, 
        Name NVARCHAR(255),
        Const1 DECIMAL(18,10),
        Const2 DECIMAL(18,10),
        Const3 DECIMAL(18,10),
        Const4 DECIMAL(18,10)
    );
```

I want to add in a field called "Calculation". The user has to specify in that field how the constants are to be applied (i.e. "Const1 * Const2 + (Const3 - Const4)").

I've got a function that has the formula hard coded but I want to be able to dynamically map the table columns to the "Calculation" field. Is this possible? If I'm getting a table entry like:

```
ID| Name         | Const1 | Const2 | Const3 | Const4 | Calculation
1 | Calculation1 |      5 |      3 |      2 |      9 | Const1 * Const2 + (Const3 - Const4)
```

Then in my function, can I dynamically make the calculation and return that as an output? Am I approaching this problem the correct way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Tom H I've added in the new field with the formula as described above. I'm trying to find out how to do a mapping to a column name based on a varchar column entry.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do that in a layer above the database layer?

Comment: @TT. It would but there is an external system that is reliant on the value that the scalar function provides. I don't have any control over it.. they want to be able to pull the calculated value.

Comment: Any chance you could the process that inserts these rows and store the computation instead of the formula? SQL just isn't designed for this kind of thing. It is risky, brittle and horribly inefficient.

Comment: Since you're limited to four "constants" is it possible that the number of formulas is limited too?

Comment: @shawnt00 There are up to 10 constants available and more could be added if necessary. Even if I only was restricted to 4, there could be many formulas that could be derived.

Comment: @SeanLange I could save the calculation (given the example above) as "5 * 3 + (2 - 9)" but how would I go about interpreting that in SQL? I can't use dynamic SQL to evaluate that.

Comment: Looks like this is up your alley: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Recursive+function/76077/ I imagine you could adapt an RPN calculator/evaluator to SQL pretty easily.

Comment: @RizJa You haven't explained why this needs to be a function. Sean Lange's suggestion is to evaluate the expression at the point you insert the row (or change a value).

Comment: Doing this in a function is going to be painful. You can't use dynamic sql in a function (well at least not directly), a scalar function for this is going to be horrible for performance and you are going to have to use dynamic sql to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use dynamic SQL with `sp_executesql` or `EXEC`. I don't recall if those can be used in a UDF or not and there are some issues to be aware of, such as SQL Injection and possible performance issues. I don't have time to test whether or not this works in a UDT, but you would want something like:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(Calculation, 'Const1', Const1), 'Const2', Const2)... + ' AS result'
FROM My_Table
WHERE ID = 1

EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: This would have been amazing but unfortunately it looks like dynamic SQL can't be used in UDFs.

Comment: It looks like that is indeed the case. I'm not sure what other solutions there might be if you're tied to using a function. I'm assuming that your calculations are more complex then just simple math with constants?

Comment: The calculations are fairly simple. There's up to ten constants that can be used but it's still simple math. If there weren't dependencies on this function, I'd be open to using a stored procedure instead of a UDF but unfortunately that's not a simple task in my case.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't just store the result in the table and simply select it from there?

Comment: The UDF has a couple of parameters, which it uses to dynamically generate a couple of values (from other functions) that are integrated into the formula. For that reason I can't store the result in a table.

Comment: After extensive research in trying to get it done.. it doesn't seem possible. The option that seems most suitable is to convert the UDF to a stored procedure and go about it that way. Still marking this as the answer since this'd be the approach to take within the SP.

Comment: I did some additional digging and also couldn't come up with any way to do it in a function except to use an extended stored procedure within the function. While that might be technically feasible, it's very inadvisable.